# How to attach my domain with bind in real www

Tags: networking, dns, ubuntu-12.04, bind, debian-wheezy

I install bind9, with apache.

my dig, host, nslookup and ping provide this info:

my system ip address: 59.177.154.251

my domain name: imsingh.com

my domain registrar: GoDaddy.com

When i write imsingh.com in my system browser's address bar the website opens properly.

**my question: What I need todo further so that imsingh.com opens the website hosted on my system.** when I or You, or anyone else clicks [www.imsingh.com](http://imsingh.com) then *the website hosted on my system is not launched.* I want to know how **i should change namesever with ns1.imsingh.com & ns2.imsingh.com** at GoDaddy.com because when i change them GoDaddy says `nameserver not registered`

```
            # dig imsingh.com

            ; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> imsingh.com
            ;; global options: +cmd
            ;; Got answer:
            ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15453
            ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

            ;; QUESTION SECTION:
            ;imsingh.com.           IN  A

            ;; ANSWER SECTION:
            imsingh.com.        86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251

            ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
            imsingh.com.        86400   IN  NS  NS1.imsingh.com.
            imsingh.com.        86400   IN  NS  NS2.imsingh.com.

            ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
            NS1.imsingh.com.    86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251
            NS2.imsingh.com.    86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251

            ;; Query time: 0 msec
            ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
            ;; WHEN: Fri Aug  9 16:01:25 2013
            ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113

            # host imsingh.com
            imsingh.com has address 59.177.154.251
            imsingh.com mail is handled by 10 MX1.imsingh.com.

            # nslookup imsingh.com
            Server:     127.0.0.1
            Address:    127.0.0.1#53

            Name:   imsingh.com
            Address: 59.177.154.251


            # ping imsingh.com
            PING imsingh.com (59.177.154.251) 56(84) bytes of data.
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=1 ttl=254 time=0.539 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=2 ttl=254 time=0.535 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=3 ttl=254 time=0.529 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=4 ttl=254 time=0.534 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=5 ttl=254 time=0.534 ms
            ^C
            --- imsingh.com ping statistics ---
            5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3997ms
            rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.529/0.534/0.539/0.014 ms
```

Data for ip address

```
            # dig -x 59.177.154.251

            ; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> -x 59.177.154.251
            ;; global options: +cmd
            ;; Got answer:
            ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27574
            ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

            ;; QUESTION SECTION:
            ;251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

            ;; ANSWER SECTION:
            251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa. 604800 IN  PTR IMSINGH.COM.

            ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
            59.in-addr.arpa.    604800  IN  NS  IMSINGH.COM.

            ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
            IMSINGH.COM.        86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251

            ;; Query time: 0 msec
            ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
            ;; WHEN: Fri Aug  9 16:05:06 2013
            ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100


            # host 59.177.154.251
            251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer IMSINGH.COM.


            # host 59.177.154.251
            251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer IMSINGH.COM.


            # ping 59.177.154.251
            PING 59.177.154.251 (59.177.154.251) 56(84) bytes of data.
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=1 ttl=254 time=0.679 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=2 ttl=254 time=0.529 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=3 ttl=254 time=0.533 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=4 ttl=254 time=0.689 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=5 ttl=254 time=0.523 ms
            ^C
            --- 59.177.154.251 ping statistics ---
            5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3998ms
            rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.523/0.590/0.689/0.080 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Your domain is well visible from the internet, as far as I see, for `nslookup imsingh.com` and `nslookup www.imsingh.com` I get the IP address you mentioned. To properly be able to test it yourself, you need to use an external connection so that you do not end up using your local network interfaces.

The problem as far as I see is that your server is not responding in any way, which makes me think that there might be a firewall that is dropping all traffic to port 80 in front of your server. Open that port for connections from the internet in the FW and likely you would have your site online. Alternatively, if there is a sort of a proxy between the internet and the web server, that might also be badly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing multiple problems, the first one is with DNS.  While your local nameserver is working, this is not being read externally.  There are, I suspect, 2 reasons for this.

First off, in order to run your own nameservers most TLD's (for example .com) require a minimum of 2 nameservers, and you only appear to have 1 configured - so it won't allow you to register this.

Secondly you have an issue with "glue records".  Because you are wanting to us a subdomain (ns1.mysingh.com) as domain name server for register mysingh.com there is a problem that the root server does not know where to find ns1.mysingh.com because it does does not know how to reach mysingh.com.    In order to fix this you need to either use different domain name (which the root nameservers know - for example godaddys) and then point the A records to your site, bypassing your nameservers, or you need to get your registrar to register your nameservers as "glue records", which are hardcoded IP addresses associated with the nameservers in the root zone file.

The first problem to solve (if you want to run your own nameservers) is to find someone willing to act as a secondary nameserver [ or another identically configured primary server ].